# OpenSSL KEYUPDATE and "SSL_key_update:wrong ssl version"

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, aes

I am using Ubuntu 19.04 which ships with OpenSSL 1.1.1b. The system info is below. I am encountering *`SSL_key_update:wrong ssl version`* when transferring large docs during *`KEYUPDATE`*.

I am starting my server with:

```
openssl s_server -accept 443 -cert /app/keys/cert.pem  -key /app/keys/private.key
```

I am connecting to the server with the following command using AES128:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -cipher AES128-GCM-SHA256 -tls1_2
```

Sometimes it works, particularly if I am sending less than 100KB. However, with larger transfers it usually stops with:

```
KEYUPDATE
140048546800768:error:1420310A:SSL routines:SSL_key_update:wrong ssl version:../ssl/ssl_lib.c:2090:
```

[Others have seen this too](https://github.com/boostorg/beast/issues/1467) but they don't seem to conclude which aspect of the configuration is causing the problem.

Interestingly, if I run an older openssl 1.1.0h-fips `s_client` against this same 1.1.1b server, it works just fine when using the same `-cipher AES128-GCM-SHA256 -tls1_2` options. And in fact it says:

```
Protocol  : TLSv1.2
Cipher    : AES128-GCM-SHA256
```

As did the 1.1.1b client... it's just that the 1.1.1b client doesn't seem to be working.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

---

Here is the system info:

```
cli5# openssl version -a
OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
built on: Wed Apr 17 16:50:04 2019 UTC
platform: debian-amd64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: gcc -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -Wall -Wa,--noexecstack -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/openssl-FmdPCA/openssl-1.1.1b=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPADLOCK_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
OPENSSLDIR: "/usr/lib/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
cli5# cat /proc/version
Linux version 5.0.0-17-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-015) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Ubuntu 8.3.0-6ubuntu1)) #18-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 4 15:34:08 UTC 2019
cli5#
```

Comment: Are you typing a line beginning with K or k, or redirecting or piping such data even though your posted command doesn't show it? OpenSSL 1.1.1 implements TLS1.3, and as a result `s_client` has a new feature to do key update when the input line begins with K or k _and_ the connection is using TLS1.3, which your connection is not hence the error. This has nothing to do with which ciphersuite is selected on the connection and you would get the same error for any other negotiated ciphersuite (although for 1.3 the only ciphersuites that exist are variants of AES-GCM, AES-CCM, and ChaCha-Poly).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 That is interesting. Indeed, typing K or k causes the error more immediately. However, the data I was piping does not contain a line starting with "K" or "k", and it is trying to do the KEYUPDATE anyway.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085. Well this is interesting. I was sending an 18MB file, containing many lines, none starting with "K" or "k". But if I remove the "k" or "K" in specific places where it stopped (and the "K" or "k" was NOT at the beginning of the line) then it seems to work. I wonder why those "K"/"k" were special... Can the "K"/"k" feature be turned off to confirm that this is the issue?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085. It appears that "p" and "P" also cause similar issues. If I remove all the "k", "K", "p", and "P" from the data, then I can send large files in both directions.

Comment: Okay, I checked the code, and it's actually beginning of _buffer_ not _line_. For user input (which was easier to test) buffer=line, but for piped input usually not and for redirected never. I _think_ what matters is multiples of 8K (8192), but didn't go the effort of testing that. P and p should _not_ be special; Q R and maybe B _should_ -- but also on older versions (back to 0.9.8); only K k should be _different_ in 1.1.1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`s_client` is a test tool that interprets certain letters received on stdin to perform certain operations. The KeyUpdate operation is triggered via <kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>. However, KeyUpdate only makes sense when `TLSv1.3` has been negotiated. However, you have explicitly requested `TLSv1.2` only on the command line. Using <kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd> under those circumstances results in the "wrong ssl version" error.

You can switch off the interactive commands using the `-ign_eof` option - although that does have the unfortunate side effect of keeping `s_client` running, even after a file that you have piped through it has all been sent.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, This option resolve my issue.

```
-ign_eof

openssl s_client -starttls smtp -crlf -connect smtp.acbd.com:587 -ign_eof
```